# Rust: designing around the orphan rule for external traits

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm learning Rust by implementing an API to query a database, using Actix-web and Diesel. I want to be able to store Books, and a book looks like this:

```
pub struct Book {
    pub id: i32,
    pub isbn: ISBN,
    pub title: String,
    pub author: String,
    pub edition: String,
    pub created_at: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}
```

The component giving me difficulties is ISBN, for which I'm using the external crate [`isbnid::isbn::ISBN`](https://docs.rs/isbnid/0.1.3/isbnid/isbn/index.html). It doesn't implement `Serialize, Deserialize,` or `Queryable`, which I need. I have gotten around this for the `serde` types following [this](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html) serde guide.

Unfortunately I cannot do the same for `Queryable`, so I end up with the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ISBN: diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Text, Pg>` is not satisfied
```

From [this post](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html) I understand that I cannot implement the external trait `Queryable` on the external type `ISBN` due to the orphan rule. However, I would like my `Book` struct to have the ISBN type, because it provides nice functionality to do with a book's ISBN, such as verifying validity.

My question: how do I idiomatically work around this rule in my design? Is storing ISBN as a string and manually verifying ISBNs are correct the best I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out `deserialize_as` in the diesel documentation.